# How to accomplish scrolling text on Twitter home page?

Tags: html, css, twitter

On the twitter home page (not logged in), there a scrolling text in the middle below the logo. How is this accomplished? It stops scrolling when mouseover and also has a popup dialog on relevant text.
Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [jQuery marquee plugin](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/) that will give you a good head start. It shouldn't be difficult to build the tooltip stuff on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could accomplish it, but I imagine its using Ajax to fill an HTML div with the results of a call to Twitter's Services. Its then probably using JQuery to scroll the div, as well as display those fancy tooltips.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at this in Firebug.

The topics are being loaded via JSON and the Twitter API and then they are calling fronts.js (**http://a2.twimg.com/a/1272578449/javascripts/fronts.js**) in association with jQuery.